# 2D Array - in PASCAL with loop

Tags: arrays, loops, pascal

I need to write a program which demonstrates 2d array, the program need to ask for student name and then the mark.. and this is for 15 students. At the end program outputs 15 names with their marks next to it.

I don't know how to manipulate 2D arrays accurately, I managed to do simple version without using for loop.

`

```
table: array[1..2, 1..15] of string;   {2 rows for 15 columns}


begin
clrscr;
writeln('Enter 15 student names, and a set of marks after each ');
writeln('With marks you can enter more marks after comma for e.g. 34, 26, 31 etc.');

writeln('Enter NAME and SURNAME of STUDENT NR 1 or q to quit ');
read(table[1][1]);                    {read name in row 1 col 1}
readln;                                      
writeln(' Enter MARKS of STUDENT NR 1 ');
read(table[2][1]);                     { read mark in row 2 col 1}
readln;             
clrscr;

writeln('Enter NAME and SURNAME of STUDENT NR 2 or q to quit ');
read(table[1][2]);
readln;             
writeln('Enter MARKS of STUDENT NR 2 ');
read(table[2][2]);
readln;             read marks into row 2 column 2}

`
```

etc. up to student nr 15... but I know I could use two for loops to do that for me instead of copying  code for each student... same for output... I've spend many hours to figure out how to do it with different tries... but still Im confused with using two for loops and indexing this array correctly.

could someone help me with this appropriate looping ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, Pascal, haven't seen it for a very long time! It's a good language for learning to program.

Try something like this..

```
program testarray2d;

uses crt;

var
    table: array[1..2, 1..15] of string;   {2 rows for 15 columns}
    counter: Integer;

Begin
     writeln('Enter 15 student names, and a set of marks after each ');
     writeln('With marks you can enter more marks after comma for e.g. 34, 26, 31 etc.');

      For counter := 1 to 15 do 
       Begin
        writeln('Enter NAME and SURNAME of STUDENT NR ');
        write(counter);
        write(' or q to quit ');
        readln(table[1][counter]);                                
        writeln('Enter MARKS of STUDENT NR ');
        write(counter);
        readln(table[2][counter]);                                  
        clrscr;
      End;
End.
```

Please let me know if it works, because I haven't tested it.

Comment: This  Works fine however how can I output both columns and rows in the same way ? i've tried write(table[1,2][counter]) but this doesn't work as it should... and I've tried  write(table[1][counter]) this works but only for the names, any idea how can I put marks next to each name ?

Comment: With  `write(' '); write(table[2][counter]);` after  `write(table[1][counter]);`

Comment: Thank you very much I will remember now how to use those 2d arrays and I'm closer to understand it properly !

Comment: No probs! Hope you understood how to build the `for` loop too. You can mark the question as answered.